# Turn option value into an array

Tags: php, arrays, html-select

I am creating a select form using a foreach loop as shown below:

```
$json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"23", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$decode = json_decode($json, false);

echo'<select>';
foreach($decode as $key) {
   echo '<option value="'.$key->Name.'"></option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

This will display the following HTML:

```
<select>
   <option value="Jim">
   <option value="Bob">
</select>
```

How would I create an array which has all of the `option` values, like this:

```
$array = array('Jim', 'Bob');
```

Comment: Use domdocument to parse HTML

Comment: Why not `$array[] = $key->Name;` ?

Comment: @splash58 inside the loop?

Comment: @splash58 I didn't know it was as simple as that.... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to define your options in php in an array and display this array as option in your page.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do this. Is there not a way around?

Comment: @TheCodesee  DID THIS select box is going to submit through some form or you want it on same page?

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`loadHTMLFile`**](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)   to read html element.
Store html in a file let say `filename.html`

Inside `filename.html`

```
<select>
   <option value="1">
   <option value="Bob">
   <option value="2343">
</select>
```

and call the file as

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");
//echo $doc->saveHTML();
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('option');
$array = [];
if (!is_null($elements)) {
    //print_r($elements);
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        // echo "<br/>". $element->nodeName. ": ";
        $array[] = $element->getAttribute('value');
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

**UPDATED**

```
 $json = '[{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"23", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]';
$decode = json_decode($json, false);
$str="";
echo'<select>';
foreach($decode as $key) {
   echo $xml = '<option value="'.$key->Name.'"></option>';
   $str.=$xml;
}
echo'</select>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
//echo $doc->saveHTML();
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('option');
$array = [];
if (!is_null($elements)) {
    //print_r($elements);
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        // echo "<br/>". $element->nodeName. ": ";
        $array[] = $element->getAttribute('value');
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Hi, please take a look at my update post. I have added more information

Comment: Same approach but use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php for your updated code!!

Comment: What if I wanted to run the code on the same page as the HTML?

Comment: store html in variable and use http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php and use `$doc->loadHTML($myhtml);`

Comment: I tried your code but it only returns the first option value in the array: https://3v4l.org/qultA

Comment: It still displays both `<option>` elements though. I tried your updated code but the `<option>` elements are missing

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have broken HTML string: do you have `</option>` tag for each of `<option>`?

Try this if you have:

```
<?php
$xml = '<select>
   <option value="1"></option>
   <option value="Bob"></option>
   <option value="2343"></option>
</select>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadXML($xml);

$values = array();

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('option') as $option) {
  $values[] = $option->getAttribute('value');
}

print_r($values);
```

Comment: Try to copy my code to empty new file and run `php yourfile.php`. I have 3 values in array.

Comment: Hi, please take a look at my update post. I have added more information.

Comment: This is the result of your code: https://3v4l.org/dPElV _(it still only returns one option in the array)

Comment: Check $xml. You replace thos value in each foreach loop. So you echo all of xml, but loadXML only for last iteration of foreach.